# Why is an automatic comment created whenever I link to a post?

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I write a new post or article, and link to another article or post, the other post/article gets a comment containing a link to and content of the new article.
[image: Screenshot of such a comment]

The comments section of WordPress shows author as *Title and new post link*.

For example, I wrote an article on how to root an Android 6 smartphone. Then I wrote another article about Xiaomi. In this article I added a link to the "Root Android 6 smartphone" article, which suddenly has a comment as shown in the screenshot.

How do I avoid creating these automatic comments?

There are no comment plugins except Akismet Anti-Spam (and this plugin does not flag the comment as spam).

Answer (score 1):

This is the *pingback* feature ([documentation](https://en.support.wordpress.com/comments/pingbacks/)), which is meant to post a comment on a post when the post is mentioned somewhere else - also on the same blog.

If you want to link to a post on your own blog without pinging it, you can do so by *not* using the absolute URL when linking. From the documentation:

> To prevent self-pings, remove the domain from the link, keeping only
>   the slug — the part of the URL that comes after the “.com.” Instead of
>   this:
>
> `http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/03/26/twitter-widget` use only this:
>
> `/2009/03/26/twitter-widget`

If you want to *completely* disable ping-backs (also from other blogs), you can uncheck the *Allow pingbacks & trackbacks* checkbox when editing a post.